# Matplotlib Gridspsec spacing between rows

Tags: matplotlib

I have images with three different dimensions (WxH): 4 images with (174x145), 4 images with (145x145) and 4 images with (145x174). I could remove space between columns, but I cannot remove space between rows. Any suggestions?
[image]

This is my code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
gs = fig.add_gridspec(3, 4, hspace=0, wspace=0)
for r in range(3):
    for c in range(4):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[r, c])
        ax.imshow(slices[r][c].T, origin="lower", cmap="gray")
        ax.axis("off")
```

Comment: It would be helpful to show the code used to create the axes.

Comment: You can set the relative heights of the gridspec using `height_ratio` kwarg: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html

Comment: @DizietAsahi I have added my code

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you need to set the `height_ratios` for your GridSpec, but that's not enough. You also need to adjust the size of your figure so that the width/height ratio of the figure matches the total width/height ratios of your images. But herein lies another problem, in that the axes will be scaled when plotting the images (because of [`aspect='equal'`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect)) and because they do not all have the same width/height ratios.

The solution that I'm proposing is first to calculate what the dimensions of figures would be, once stretched to a common width size, then use that correct information to adjust the figure size and the height_ratios of the GridSpec.

```
# this is just for visualization purposes
cmaps = iter([   'flag', 'prism', 'ocean', 'gist_earth', 'terrain', 'gist_stern',
            'gnuplot', 'gnuplot2', 'CMRmap', 'cubehelix', 'brg',
            'gist_rainbow', 'rainbow', 'jet', 'nipy_spectral', 'gist_ncar'])



sizes = [(174,145), (145,145), (145,174)]

# create random images
p = []
for s in sizes:
    p.append([np.random.random(size=s) for _ in range(4)])
p = np.array(p)


max_w = max([w for w,h in sizes])
new_sizes = np.array([(w*max_w/w, h*max_w/w) for w,h in sizes])
print(new_sizes)

total_w = 4*new_sizes[:,0].sum()
total_h = 3*new_sizes[:,1].sum()
eps=10/total_w
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(eps*total_w,eps*total_h))
gs0 = matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec(3,4, height_ratios=[h for w,h in new_sizes], hspace=0, wspace=0)
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(4):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(gs0[i,j])
        ax.imshow(p[i,j].T, origin="lower", cmap=next(cmaps))
        ax.set_axis_off()
```

[image]

Unfortunately, this solution gets you *almost* to the desired output, but not quite, probably due to some rounding effect. But it close enough that I think you could use `aspect='auto'` if you can live with pixels that are ever so slightly not square.

```
(...)
ax.imshow(p[i,j].T, aspect='auto', origin="lower", cmap=next(cmaps))
(...)
```

[image]